# Websphere 8.5 deployment issue with SLF4j

Tags: spring, websphere, slf4j

I am working on one of the upgrade in a spring based soap web service. The service is working fine on the tomcat server but when we are trying to deploy on the WAS 8.5 it is throwing the AbstractMethod Error.

00000089 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [spring-ws] in application: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org/slf4j/spi/LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:118)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:345)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1369)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:638)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:604)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:426)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)

Comment: Do you have multiple copies of SLF4J in your application?  If so, it's possible that you're picking up a version of the implementation that doesn't have that method.

Comment: I checked it and see only one version of the slf4j. Is it possible that the slf4j is existing in WAS library?

Comment: What version of WAS are you on?  A related fix for SLF4J went into 8.5.5.3 -  https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg1PM97575

Comment: was version -8.5.5.9

Comment: Try setting PARENT_LAST classloader option on your web module and see if it will help.